# NHibernate - Is it possible to apply filters on UPDATE/DELETE?

Tags: nhibernate, filter, sql-update, sql-delete

I know that we can easily apply filters to query with additional `where` conditions with NHibernate, but is it possible to apply a filter when doing an update or delete?

If it is, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible, using HQL (Hibernate Query Language)

Here's an example of a batch update

```
IQuery updateQuery = this.Session.CreateQuery("update TransferItem set Status = :newStatus where Status = :oldStatus")
                        .SetParameter("oldStatus", DownloadStatus.Active)
                       .SetParameter("newStatus", DownloadStatus.Queued);
updateQuery.ExecuteUpdate();
```

NHibernate applies the configured mappings to create and run the following SQL:

```
 update cms_TransferItem set Status=@p0 where Status=@p1
```

Here's an example of a batch delete

```
IQuery deleteQuery = this.Session.CreateQuery("delete TransferItem ti WHERE ti.Status = :statusToGo")
                           .SetParameter("statusToGo", DownloadStatus.Completed);

deleteQuery.ExecuteUpdate();
```

Which executes SQL like this:

```
 delete from cms_TransferItem where Status=@p0
```

You might ask, if you have to work with a query language, why not just write raw SQL? When you use HQL you are working with the conceptual business objects that the rest of the .NET code is working with. The benefits of an ORM tool is that, for much of the code, the database tables and object-to-table mappings are abstracted away. With HQL you are continuing to interact with the object layer, rather than directly with the database tables.

Comment: Interesting, but sadly, in my case, this wouldn't work because we are using a generic repository pattern. The idea is to apply a custom fuction call from the database on update or delete. Is there a way to do it with a simple `session.SaveOrUpdate` or with a `session.Delete` call? (for each delete or update, the filter would generate something like: `where IsOperationAllowedFromUser(:userId, :itemId)`)

Comment: @Sam9291 Is `IsOperationAllowedFromUser` an SQL function or a .NET function?

Comment: It would be an SQL function

Comment: @Sam9291 - You can invoke custom SQL functions as part of HQL. First, you have to extend the dialect so that it knows of the function. Here's a blog post http://ayende.com/blog/1720/using-sql-functions-in-nhibernate